# .dot() product for VectorXcd in Eigen c++

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm trying to figure out if this is a bug in Eigen or something I'm doing wrong. I simply want the dot product of two complex vectors [ 1 , i] and [1 , -i]. The answer is 1*1 + i*(-i) = 2. But Eigen gives zero as answer. See code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <map>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std; 

int main( void ){


    VectorXcd xd0(2); 
    complex<double> c_i( 0.0 , 1.0 ); 
    xd0[0] = 1.0 ;   
    xd0[1] =  c_i; 

    VectorXcd xd0conj = xd0.conjugate();
    cout <<" vec is \n" << xd0 <<endl;
    cout <<" conj vec is \n" << xd0conj <<endl;

    cout << "eigen dot = " << (xd0conj).dot(xd0 ) <<endl; 

    complex<double> outVal = 0.0; 
    for( int a=0; a<xd0.size(); a++){
        outVal += xd0[a]*xd0conj[a]; 
    }
    cout << "naive dot = " << outVal<<endl;

};
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#adb71ddef4955ae7d353df12d05665191):

"
If the scalar type is complex numbers, then this function returns the hermitian (sesquilinear) dot product, conjugate-linear in the first variable and linear in the second variable.
"

This product is often used, for example in [quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(physics)#Hermitian_operators).
It computes conj(x)*y which is what you are seeing. I guess you want the simple / ordinary dot:

```
cout << "eigen dot = " << xd0conj.transpose()*xd0 <<endl;
```

This outputs

```
eigen dot = (2,0)
```